# Adding a textbox for each checkbox option

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form that gets the options for the checkboxes dynamically from a list based on the value the user has entered. I need to enter a text box next to each of the checkboxes, is this possible in InfoPath?
If so, how can I acheive this?

Ex:
Acquisition Types: Fruit, Vegetables

If user select Fruit, the check box options would be Apple, Oranges etc.

I want a text box next to each fruit so that the user can enter the quantity for each fruit selected.